# how do you disable exit pop up?

Tags: javascript

I am using this script, which makes an alert pop up when they try to exit the page. But the problem is that it still pops up when I click a button which redirects to another page. I want to disable it when clicking buttons. How can I do this?

```
<script language="javascript">
(function() {
    var __redirect_to = 'http://google.ca';//put redirect URL here

    var _tags = ['button', 'input', 'a'], _els, _i, _i2;
    for(_i in _tags) {
        _els = document.getElementsByTagName(_tags[_i]);
        for(_i2 in _els) {
            if((_tags[_i] == 'input' && _els[_i2].type != 'button' && _els[_i2].type != 'submit') || _els[_i2].target == '_blank') continue;
            _els[_i2].onclick = function() {window.onbeforeunload = function(){};}
        }
   }

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.onbeforeunload = function() {};
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.location.href = __redirect_to;
            }, 500);
        },5);
        return 'Do you really want to leave? Stay to go somewhere else.';
    }
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
_els[_i2].onclick = function() {window.onbeforeunload = function(){};}
```

and these:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {};
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.location.href = __redirect_to;
        }, 500);
    },5);
    return 'Do you really want to leave? Stay to go somewhere else.';
}
```

Comment: I need it to show that and redirect to another page if they try to exit. but not when clicking buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you analyze it, you can see that, there is a tag name array

```
var _tags = ['button', 'input', 'a'], _els, _i, _i2;
```

and for each of element in it it apply an onlick event

```
for(_i in _tags) {
    _els = document.getElementsByTagName(_tags[_i]);
    for(_i2 in _els) {
        if((_tags[_i] == 'input' && _els[_i2].type != 'button' && _els[_i2].type != 'submit') || _els[_i2].target == '_blank') continue;
        _els[_i2].onclick = function() {window.onbeforeunload = function(){};}
    }
}
```

so just remove the tag name 'button' of the array

```
var _tags = ['input', 'a'], _els, _i, _i2;
```

Comment: But the button is not actually a button. its an clickable image. <a class="Style3" href="javascript:getIt_wc();"><img src="image.PNG" /></a></div>